# How to get cumulative sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm kinda new here and I need your help guys, I have a data that contains a list of invoices, I want to check if each invoice is paid or not.

This is my data:

```
ID     | JO | C. ID  | L |Invoice |Amount |Payment 
279810 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0001 | 55638 | 170000
279812 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0002 | 40720 | 170000
279814 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0003 | 76644 | 170000
279868 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0004 | 51500 | 170000
```

And this is the result I want:

```
ID     | JO | C. ID  | L |Invoice |Amount |Payment |Rest   | State
279810 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0001 | 55638 | 170000 | 0     | PAID
279812 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0002 | 40720 | 170000 | 0     | PAID
279814 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0003 | 76644 | 170000 | 3002  | P. PAYMENT
279868 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0004 | 51500 | 170000 | 51500 | NOT PAID
```

Thank you in advance.

I have another case when there is only a partial payment like the example below:

```
ID     | JO | C. ID  | L |Invoice |Amount |Payment 
279810 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0001 | 55638 | 50000
279812 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0002 | 40720 | 50000
```

The result I get:

```
ID     | JO | C. ID  | L |Invoice |Amount |Payment |Rest   | State
279810 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0001 | 55638 | 50000  | 55638 | NOT PAID
279812 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0002 | 40720 | 50000  | 40720 | NOT PAID
```

The result I want:

```
ID     | JO | C. ID  | L |Invoice |Amount |Payment |Rest   | State
279810 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0001 | 55638 | 50000  |  5638 | P. PAYMENT
279812 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0002 | 40720 | 50000  | 40720 | NOT PAID
```

Comment: Best to post your sample data and desired results as TEXT and not images.

Comment: What are the column names here? What signifies a paid invoice?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I did it. Thank you.

Comment: @hmzshl please include the logic to identify if a invoice is paid or not

Comment: @Isaac The columns names are: ID,JO,Customer ID,Invoice,Payment.

Comment: @hmzshl, please update your question with the column names

Comment: @hmzshl It looks to me like you have 7 columns in your data, but you only provided 5 column names. Something is missing.

Comment: Show us your SQL that isn't working

Comment: @Squirrel I updated my post, maybe it's a bit clear now..

Comment: @Isaac I updated my post, take a look

Comment: @hmzshl How can you calcute based these columns where payment is paid or not? Why Payment contains 17000 for all and Rest Coumn Logic ?

Comment: @RamAnugandula I have one payment which is 170000, and multiple invoices, this payment supposed to pay the first invoices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is interesting since there can be cases that won't have any partial payment, following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ID INT,JO VARCHAR(10),CID VARCHAR(10),L VARCHAR(10), Invoice VARCHAR(10), Amount NUMERIC(10,2), Payment NUMERIC(10,2))
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
(279810,'B1','CL0001','a','FA0001',55638,170000),
(279812,'B1','CL0001','a','FA0002',40720,170000),
(279814,'B1','CL0001','a','FA0003',73642,170000),
(279868,'B1','CL0001','a','FA0004',51500,170000),
(279868,'B1','CL0001','a','FA0004',200,170000),
(279868,'B1','CL0001','a','FA0004',1234678,170000),
(279868,'B1','CL0001','a','FA0004',90,170000),
(279870,'B1','CL0002','a','FA0005',10000,60000),
(279871,'B1','CL0002','a','FA0006',15000,60000),
(279872,'B1','CL0002','a','FA0007',30000,60000),
(279873,'B1','CL0002','a','FA0008',25000,60000),
(279810,'B1','CL0003','a','FA0001',55638,50000),
(279812,'B1','CL0003','a','FA0002',40720,50000)

SELECT ID,JO,CID,L,Invoice,Amount,Payment
    ,CASE WHEN t.[Balance] >=0 THEN 0 
          WHEN t.[Balance] <0 AND LAG(t.[Balance],1,1) OVER( PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) > 0 THEN ABS(t.[Balance])
          ELSE [Amount] END AS [Balance Amount]
    ,CASE WHEN t.[Balance] >=0 THEN 'Paid'
          WHEN t.[Balance] <0 AND LAG(t.[Balance],1,1) OVER( PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) > 0 THEN 'Partial Payment'
          ELSE 'Not Paid' END AS [Status]
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) Cumulative
    FROM #temp ) A
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(Payment - Cumulative)) AS T(Balance)
```

Result is as below,

```
ID      JO  CID     L   Invoice  Amount     Payment     Balance Amount  Status
279810  B1  CL0001  a   FA0001   55638.00   170000.00   0.00            Paid
279812  B1  CL0001  a   FA0002   40720.00   170000.00   0.00            Paid
279814  B1  CL0001  a   FA0003   73642.00   170000.00   0.00            Paid
279868  B1  CL0001  a   FA0004   51500.00   170000.00   51500.00        Not Paid
279868  B1  CL0001  a   FA0004   200.00     170000.00   200.00          Not Paid
279868  B1  CL0001  a   FA0004   1234678.00 170000.00   1234678.00      Not Paid
279868  B1  CL0001  a   FA0004   90.00      170000.00   90.00           Not Paid
279870  B1  CL0002  a   FA0005   10000.00   60000.00    0.00            Paid
279871  B1  CL0002  a   FA0006   15000.00   60000.00    0.00            Paid
279872  B1  CL0002  a   FA0007   30000.00   60000.00    0.00            Paid
279873  B1  CL0002  a   FA0008   25000.00   60000.00    20000.00        Partial Payment
279810  B1  CL0003  a   FA0001   55638.00   50000.00    5638.00         Partial Payment
279812  B1  CL0003  a   FA0002   40720.00   50000.00    40720.00        Not Paid
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! That's what I'm looking for. Thank you so much for your time sir!!

Comment: I have another case, when there is only one invoice and the a partial payment, the query returns 'Not Paid' instead of 'Partial Payment'

Comment: @hmzshl please update the sample data in the qn to include this scenario

Comment: can you please take a look again at my post, I edited with the other case that I have. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

to get the cumulative invoice amount use `sum(Amount) over (order by ID)`. I assumed it is in the order of `ID`. You need to partition by the Customer also. I didn't include that in the query as I am not sure what is the column name for that

The rest is not that difficult to comprehend. It is using `CASE` statement to determine if it is PAID or PARTIAL or NOT PAID

```
select  *,
        Rest    = case  when    Payment > sum(Amount) over (order by ID)
                        then    0
                        when    sum(Amount) over (order by ID) - Payment < Amount
                        then    sum(Amount) over (order by ID) - Payment
                        else    Amount
                        end,
        State   = case  when    Payment > sum(Amount) over (order by ID)
                        then    'PAID'
                        when    sum(Amount) over (order by ID) - Payment < Amount
                        then    'P. PAYMENT'
                        else    'NOT PAID'
                        end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That looks pretty much like what I'm looking for. I will try it and give you a feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Extra kudos to @Squirrel for deciphering what was really needed. I know I was not understanding. Makes sense now.

Comment: @Squirrel I tried it, it worked good for one customer, but it doesn't work well for multiple customers.. Can you please take a look to my response below. Thank you.

Comment: you will required the `partition by` as what i have stated in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well it works good for one customer, but if I have multiple customers the calculation is wrong..

This is what I got:

```
ID     | JO |Customer| L |Invoice |Amount |Payment |Rest   | State
-------+----+--------+---+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------------
279810 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0001 | 55638 | 170000 | 0     | PAID
279812 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0002 | 40720 | 170000 | 0     | PAID
279814 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0003 | 76644 | 170000 | 3002  | P. PAYMENT
279868 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0004 | 51500 | 170000 | 51500 | NOT PAID
279870 | B1 | CL0002 | a | FA0005 | 10000 | 60000  | 10000 | NOT PAID
279871 | B1 | CL0002 | a | FA0006 | 15000 | 60000  | 15000 | NOT PAID
279872 | B1 | CL0002 | a | FA0007 | 30000 | 60000  | 30000 | NOT PAID
279873 | B1 | CL0002 | a | FA0008 | 25000 | 60000  | 25000 | NOT PAID
```

And this is what I should've got:

```
ID     | JO |Customer| L |Invoice |Amount |Payment |Rest   | State
-------+----+--------+---+--------+-------+--------+-------+-------------
279810 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0001 | 55638 | 170000 | 0     | PAID
279812 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0002 | 40720 | 170000 | 0     | PAID
279814 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0003 | 76644 | 170000 | 3002  | P. PAYMENT
279868 | B1 | CL0001 | a | FA0004 | 51500 | 170000 | 51500 | NOT PAID
279870 | B1 | CL0002 | a | FA0005 | 10000 | 60000  | 0     | PAID
279871 | B1 | CL0002 | a | FA0006 | 15000 | 60000  | 0     | PAID
279872 | B1 | CL0002 | a | FA0007 | 30000 | 60000  | 0     | PAID
279873 | B1 | CL0002 | a | FA0008 | 25000 | 60000  | 20000 | P. PAYMENT
```